# Is there a better equivalent to "1 - pow(1 - x, y)"?

Tags: math, dry, simplify

In graphics programming I often deal with values in the 0-1 range and perform various mathematical operations on them, one being raising values to a power to achieve an exponential effect:

```js
Math.pow(0.75, 2); // 0.5625
```

However, sometimes I want to use an "inverted" version of this (different from raising to power of `0.5`):

```js
1 - Math.pow(1 - 0.75, 2); // 0.9375
```

This works perfectly for my purposes, but is a rather convoluted way to write out the expression, especially when it's used a lot.

I would like to know whether a function for doing this exists in mathematics or common programming languages, or if what I wrote above is *the* simplest way to achieve this effect and I should just go ahead and write my own helper functions to make it nicer to use.

Comment: 1 - Math.pow(1 - x, 2) = x*(2 - x).

Comment: Do you care about accuracy for small `x`? E.g., if `x = 1e-10` and you're using IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point, `1 - Math.pow(1-x, 2)` evaluated directly will only have around 7 accurate significant digits. There are expressions that are more robust, like `x * (2-x)`, or for a more general exponent `y` in place of `2`, `-Math.expm1(y * Math.log1p(-x))` (assuming that `expm1` and `log1p` are available in whatever `Math` happens to refer to here).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether this is the right forum for this type of question, since it's hard to answer without even knowing the programming language in use and because it's a general math question.

In any case, the non-inverted functions map the range [0, 1] onto the range [0, 1] in a way that they are continuous and monotonously increasing. The difference (controlled by the exponent) is whether at first the curve is steep and then flattens or whether it starts flat and then becomes increasingly steep. Compared to a linear/identity mapping, the curve has a belly that is above or below.

For the inverted case, you have a similar curve, only that up and down (or left and right, if you want) are mirrored. I believe flipping it vertically by applying `1 - x` and additionally doing the same with the exponent is what overcomplicates this.

Now, how to fix that? Question is what the parameters actually mean and how the source code translates to something a human can make sense of quickly. For that, it might be best to really write a helper function. However, concerning execution speed, that would require a language that does a bit of optimization like e.g. constant propagation and inlining.

In summary, I'd say that this question can't be answered in a definite way, because it depends too much on missing information and personal opinion, making it off-topic here.